# Use grid to evaluate data

Tags: python, plot, grid, evaluation

suppose I have lists like

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1,4,9,16,25]
```

I want to plot these lists, but in a way, that for example I would divide the plotted area into 4 equally big squares.

I want something like:

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid(True but into 2x2 squares)
plt.show()
```

**Additionally**, I want to be the grid not only something which looks nice on a plot but have actual purpose.

For example I want to be able to check **how many points** are in any given square I am interested in. For example if I want to check how many points are in the bottom left square (assuming we have 2x2 squares) I want to have a clear result.

Also, if possible, I want to be able to change the size/amount of squares. Maybe I want 2x2 squares but maybe I want it to be more precise and want 10x10 squares.

Finally it would be good if I decide to divide the plotted area into 10x10 squares, such that I am able to access the information about each square that the **same squares would also be shown visually on the plot**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I have edited my answer also adding the count of the points in the cells of the grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the following function that allows you to dynamically create a grid of the size (and color) you prefer above your graph. 
I give you input to the function `plot_grid()` the data you want to draw `x` and `y`, the size of the grid (`size_grid_x` and `size_grid_y`) and optionally the color (`color_`) and the degree of transparency(`alpha_`).

The function as well as drawing the plot returns a matrix `map_points` (using [np.histogram2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html)) containing the number of points in each cell of the grid.

The code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_grid(lx, ly, legend_labels=[], size_grid_x=2, size_grid_y=2, alpha_=0.9, color_='red'):

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

    min_x, max_x = np.min(np.min(lx)), np.max(np.max(lx))
    min_y, max_y = np.min(np.min(ly)), np.max(np.max(ly)) 

    ticks_x = np.arange(min_x, max_x, (max_x-min_x)/size_grid_x)
    ticks_y = np.arange(min_y, max_y, (max_y-min_y)/size_grid_y)

    ax.set_xticks(ticks_x)
    ax.set_yticks(ticks_y)
    ax.set_xlim([min_x,max_x])
    ax.set_ylim([min_y, max_y])

    ax.grid(which='major', alpha=alpha_, color=color_)
    ax.grid(True)

    if not isinstance(lx[0], list):
        lx, ly = [lx], [ly]

    map_points_tot = np.zeros((size_grid_x,size_grid_y))
    for x,y in zip(lx, ly):
        ax.scatter(x,y)
        map_points, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=[size_grid_x, size_grid_y])
        map_points_tot += map_points

    if legend_labels:    
        plt.legend(legend_labels,loc='lower right')
    plt.show()
    plt.close()

    return map_points_tot
```

### Examples of use

Given the following data:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,9,8,7]
y = [1,4,9,16,25,7,4,18]
```

It is possible to dynamically draw a grid by passing the grid dimensions as parameters to the `plot_grid()` function. For example, if I want to create a 2x2 grid:

```
map_points = plot_grid(x, y, size_grid_x=2, size_grid_y=2)

# Map points in every cell:
array([[3., 1.],
       [2., 2.]])
```

**NOTE:** **How to interpret the results in `map_points`?** 
 in this example `map_points` must be interpreted as follows: there will be 3 points in the `lower left` cell of the graph, 1 point in the `upper left` cell, 2 points in the `lower right` cell and 2 points in the `upper right` cell.
[image]

or if I want to create a 4x4 grid:

```
map_points = plot_grid(x, y, size_grid_x=4, size_grid_y=4)

# Map points in every cell:
array([[2., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

[image]

or if I want to create a green 4x3 grid:

```
plot_grid(x, y, size_grid_x=4, size_grid_y=3, color_='green')

# Map points in every cell:
array([[2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [2., 0., 1.]])
```

[image]

**EDIT**: If you want to print more data in the same graph, just switch to the functions, you just need to pass lists of lists as values, also if you want to add the legend you just need to pass the list of labels as a parameter:

```
lx = [[1,2,3,4,5,9,8,7], [5,4,10,11,3], [3,6,7,12,7,9]]
ly = [[1,4,9,16,25,7,4,18], [8,20,21,11,17], [13,8,10,12,17,19]]
legend_labels = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']

plot_grid(lx, ly, legend_labels, size_grid_x=4, size_grid_y=3)

# Map points in every cell:
array([[2., 1., 2.],
       [3., 2., 1.],
       [0., 0., 2.],
       [3., 1., 2.]])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for all that! I will go through the code and might come back with some questions :)

Comment: Things seem to work pretty well, but could you maybe explain to me how I am supposed to read the results of the histogram2d?

What exactly does:

# Map points in every cell:
array([[3., 1.],
       [2., 2.]])

Mean, in the 2x2 box case?

Comment: Let's take the first example with a `2x2` grid that returns
`[[3., 1.], [2., 2.]]`. This means that there will be 3 points in the `lower left` cell of the graph, 1 point in the `upper left` cell, 2 points in the `lower right` cell and 2 points in the `upper right` cell. It's clear?

Comment: Understood, but I think I am going to try to re-write the matrix such that it is more intuitive.
Could you maybe tell me more about the histogramm2d(...) function and what it does? All I was able to find on google was stuff about the hist(...)  function.

Comment: I updated my answer by adding the reference to the histrogram2d documentation. Can you give me an example of the format you would like to have for the map_points matrix?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html

Comment: Thanks for all that info! Now I was trying to improve the code and had issues with 1 (rather simple) thing.

I wanted to plot more than 1 list of x and y coordinates into same plot. But if I used a for loop the function printed two separate plots, instead of plotting the data of the 2 lists into one plot. 

Then I tried to fuse the x coords from file1 and x coords from file2 into one big x_total and same for y creating y_total.

This works but after thinking about it, I would like to plot dots from different lists on the same plot IF POSSIBLE with different colors and such. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, of course I can help you. But I think we're going a little too OT here with your original question. In order not to make a confession I think it is better that you ask a new question, and maybe leave the link in the comments that I come to answer you. Meanwhile, can you accept and vote for my answer here? Thanks

Comment: Everything works beautifully! The last thing I struggle with is to prepare the data in the way you did. For example lx = [[1,2,3,4,5,9,8,7], [5,4,10,11,3], [3,6,7,12,7,9]], since I am using a second function to read in the files. Could you have a look at the separate question I asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113168/merge-array-lists-into-one-array-list

Answer (score 1):

Answer your second question, If you want to print more lines in the same plot , specifying markers and color (and much more... [see](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1, y1 = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2), np.exp(np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)) + 25
x2, y2 = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2), np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)**2
x3, y3 = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2), np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)**3
x4, y4 = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2), np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)**2.5 + 10

# red dot, blue squares and green triangles.
# You can add the plots all in the same command 
plt.plot(x1, y1, 'ro', x2, y2, 'bs', x3, y3, 'g^')
# or individually
plt.plot(x4, y4, 'y*')

plt.show()
```

[image]
Here you find the table with the [matplotlib.markers](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/markers_api.html), and here the official [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/markers_api.html)

Comment: Ah yes, I understand that you can plot it like this. I was referring to the function you gave me at the beginning where we are using a function plot_grid(x,y) with fig = plt.figure and ax=add_subplot(1,1,1) and finally ax.scatter(x,y). I'd want to be able to feed multiple x and y lists (preferably using a loop) into the function and to scatter the data into the same plot.